# Batch - How to add (file names with no extension + some text + file names with extension) to a text file?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to import MP3 file names to a txt file without the extension (.mp3) and then add some extra text like "|List\Audio\MP3\|" then import mp3 file names again, this time with the extension (.mp3). the result would be something like this :

Song|List\Audio\MP3\|Song.mp3

I tried the combination of codes from different Questions but it didn't work !

Here is what I did :

```
dir /b *.mp3 > file.txt
echo "|List\\Audio\\MP3\\|"
dir /b *.mp3 >> file.txt
```

The result is something like this :

```
Song.mp3
Song.mp3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to test and tweak this for your needs:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.mp3') do echo %%~na^|List\Audio\MP3\^|%%~a>>file.txt
```

The `~n` part of the `%%a` variable returns just the filename.

Comment: Nice. almost there. the problem is it just prints the first word of the file name and ignores the rest probably due to the space between the words ! for example if the filename is Sing With Me it just returns Sing.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Forgot to add the tokens/delims.